# Does dataFrameWriter partitionBy shuffle the data?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, hdfs, partitioning

I have data partitioned in one way, I just want to partition it in another.
So it basically gonna be something like this:

```java
sqlContext.read().parquet("...").write().partitionBy("...").parquet("...")
```

I wonder does this will trigger shuffle or all data will be re-partition locally, because in this context a partition means just a directory in HDFS and data from the same partition doesn't have to be on the same node to be written in the same dir in HDFS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither `partitionBy` nor `bucketBy` shuffles the data. There are cases though, when repartitioning data first can be a good idea:

```
df.repartition(...).write.partitionBy(...)
```

Otherwise the number of the output files is bounded by number of partitions * cardinality of the partitioning column.

Comment: what should I repartition on to avoid this?